# Lower bound for divergence of matrix spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We consider a matrix $D$ of size $N \times N, N > 1$. 
Denote by $\lambda_1 \geq \ldots \geq \lambda_N$ the eigenvalues of this matrix.

The goal is to provide a lower bound for the quantity $\sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^N (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)^2$.
In case we have constants $d_1, d_2$ for which $\lambda_1 \geq d_1 > d_2 \geq \lambda_N$ it is easy to show that 
$$
\sum_{i, j = 1}^N (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)^2 \geq \frac{N}{4} (d_1 - d_2)^2.
$$
However, it is desirable to provide lower bound of the form $c N^2$, where constant $c > 0$ doesn't depend on $N$. What techniques can be used in this case?

Comment: Simple. Just put $c=0$. The lower bound is sharp. Equality holds when $D=0$.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will edit my question to make clear I want some $c > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{i, j = 1}^N (\lambda_i - \lambda_j)^2 >\sum_{i \ne j} (\lambda_i - \lambda_{i+1})^2 >  (N^2-N) \min _{i=1,..,n-1} |\lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}|
$$

Comment: Really, isn't helpful. It is a bound of the form $N c$.

Comment: Now it is better (however, you should replace $i + 1$ by $j$). But I don't know ways to estimate $\min_{i \ne j} |\lambda_i - \lambda_j|$ for a matrix in rather general form.